# How do I get JSON array list from the Server?

Tags: android, json, http, android-volley

I am using Volley in my android client to retrieve some JSON values from server.
To get Value I did the following :

```
@Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MapsActivity.this);
                request = new JsonObjectRequest(
                        Request.Method.GET, // the request method
                        "http://10.0.2.2:8080/SomeURL",
                        new JSONObject(map),
                        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(JSONObject response){

                                textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
                                textView.setText(response.toString());
                            }
                        },
                        new Response.ErrorListener() { // the error listener
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
                                textView.setText("Error::"+ error.toString());
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error:" + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        });

                queue.add(request);
            }

        });
```

And In server side I am returning the value as following:

```
  @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
        EmployeeDAO dao = new EmployeeDAO();
        List employees = dao.getEmployees();
        return employees;
    }
```

However, I am getting the values in "onErrorResponse()"
[image: Here is sample output]

Comment: JsonObjectRequest expects a JSONObject in response but you are sending a JSONArray. Either wrap the array inside a JSONObject on server side or use StringRequest to receive a string and parse it as a JSONArray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are waiting for a `JSONObject` in your code, change `JsonObjectRequest` with `JsonArrayrequest`. In `onResponse(JSONArray response)` you parse the response